# CakePHP: hasMany model association not recursively fetching

Tags: cakephp, recursion, model, associations

I have the following association:

Site - hasMany - Sitekey
Sitekey - belongsTo - Site

sites.id is primary key
sitekeys.site_id is foreign key

in site model:
var $hasMany = array('Sitekey');

the query:
$this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Sitekey.keyword_id' => $key), 'recursive' => 1));

fetching (find 'all') recursively with that association does not work.  I have tried explicitly defining the class name, foreign key, etc...

As a last ditch effort, I simply tried changing the site model to:
var $hasOne = array('Sitekey');

When I do the recursive find 'all' on this, it does the join and returns the data correctly.  Any idea what I am doing wrong or techniques I can use to debug/fix the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried providing the class and key when you specify hasMany (and belongsTo, for that matter)?

```
var $hasMany = array( 'Sitekey' => array(
  'className' => 'Site',
  'foreignKey' => 'site_id'
));
```

For me, this happens when the Inflector doesn't correctly singularize and pluralize your nouns.  I've made it a practice to always check this first.

If this does work, then in theory you should look at why it's not recognizing it.  Create another model Bar (or some other word that it knows), and give it the same associations as sitekey, and see if it works in your site.  If so, again, it's most likely the inflector on Sitekey.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something simple like this?  The $this keyword like you have used it (assuming we are in a controller) would be an instance of the controller, not the model.  Therefore, your results would be based on the default model for the controller.  Be sure your controller "uses" the model you are trying to query.

```
$results = $ModelName->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Sitekey.keyword_id' => $key), 'recursive' => 1));
```

I'd suggest looking into the containable behavior as well. You get more control than just using recursive.